# Assigning char *c[] to a double pointer in structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct like this:

```
typedef struct stringd{
char **x;
}s;
```

and a two dimensional char array declared as

```
char *c[32];
```

I am filling up the char array inside a loop and at the end passing it to the struct *s. What would be the right way of doing this?

```
s->x = &c; 
or 
s->x = c;
```

both do not seem to work.

Comment: What is `c`? It is not declared anywhere

Comment: My bad. it was a typo. Corrected it now!

Comment: A double pointer is a pointer to double :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s *t;
t->x = c;
```

[Works for me](http://ideone.com/NGDEL). Why exactly doesn't it work? What is the error message? Maybe you have confused `typedef s`, which is a type, and variable `s`?

Answer (score 2):

`c` is an array of 32 pointers to char, that is, of type `char *[32]`, and as any array, it can decay automatically and trivially into a pointer to the first element of the array, which is of type `char **`. That seems to be what you need.

`&c`, however is of type pointer to an array of 32 pointers to char, that is, `char *(*)[32]`, and you do not need that!

Your problem seems to be with the `s` and the little arrow. Try:

```
s.x = c;
```

BTW, saying *do not work* is not as useful as copying the actual error messages...